# Unspecific behavior of record set in vb6

Tags: vb6, recordset

Dear Expert 
   i have the following problem 
when i try to get the value from the record set it showing error 
 the query is

SSql = "select doj,dol,employeeid from m_employee where employeeid='" & Trim(RsCardNo!Code) & "'"
rsCardRepl.Open SSql, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
  If rsCardRepl.RecordCount > 0 Then
Dim temp As Integer
  temp = Trim(rsCardRepl!employeeId)
 rsAddPunch!PAYCODE = temp
  End If

Then the following line giving the error

temp = Trim(rsCardRepl!employeeId)

The error Number=6
Error Description =Overflow

Would please explain me why this error is coming and what is the solution

Thanks
Naval Kishor Pandey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with cursor type adOpenForwardOnly and lock type adLockReadOnly

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to define `temp` like this `Dim temp As Long`

In simple terms, an overflow error means that the value won't fit into the variable.

- A VB6 `Integer` can take values from -32,768 to 32,767
- A `Long` can take values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: when i had seen the value in the record set through debugging is 000849 and the data type of the column employeeid is int so their is no means of overflow.

Comment: I would also try removing the Trim. Change `temp = Trim(rsCardRepl!employeeId)` into `temp = rsCardRepl!employeeId` That Trim is forcing the employeeID to be converted into a String and then back to an Integer

Comment: Hi markj i had also try with  dim temp as string  and then temp = Trim(rsCardRepl!employeeId) but still i am geting the same error.